# How to do focus out handling on text box in GWT.?

Tags: java, gwt, textbox, onfocus

I am working with a GWT project and there is scenario where I enter some data in a text box but when I click out of the text box any where on the form I have to do some other operation like show entered data as a label. 
How can I achieve this in GWT.?  Is there any way to handle this focus out scenario.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually input components extend com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FocusWidget class which has method addBlurHandler. In html onblur event is the opposite of onfocus.